# xUnit v2 IUseFixture<> replacement

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit, xunit.net

I'm trying to upgrade to xUnit 2 beta (mostly because of better test discovery) but stumbled over `IUseFixture<>`:

```
public abstract class TestCaseBase : IUseFixture<SelfHostFixture> 
{ /*common stuff here*/ }

public class Controller1Test : TestCaseBase {}

public class Controller2Test : TestCaseBase {}
```

I found that new `IClassFixture<>` was almost what I needed except the fixture was created/disposed for every descendant classes (`Controller1Test`, `Controller2Test`) instead of just once. Well, I could move `IClassFixture<SelfHostFixture>` declaration to every test class from the base but why would I setup/dispose my server multiple times? `ICollectionFixture<>` didn't worked for me (the fixture's ctor was never fired).

Basically, what I want is:

1. "Per run" fixture (must be instantiated only once per tests run)
2. Enable parallel runs because my tests are just stateless HTTP calls (I think `ICollectionFixture<>` won't work at all because tests within same collection cannot be run in parallel, right?)

What am I missing?

Comment: Just in case you haven't looked yet,I'd look at the github issues for similar issues and/or docs for the various IXXXFixture and ctor arg mechanisms to see if you can find the right way to manage it

Comment: This seems related: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9748

Comment: It was an issue with beta build I used. In 2.0 release it's fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer: use ICollectionFixture

See http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html